# Laravel url routes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, routes

I have encountered a problem with my routes in Laravel.
Im fairly new to laravel and coding in general, but i had no problems with my routes when working on Mint.

Now i switched to win8 and i can't seem to acces localhost/about.

I get this error:

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\PagesController does not exist
```

But my routes.php look like this:

```
Route::get('about', 'PagesController@about');
```

Under http>Controllers i have created `PagesController.php`

yet i get the error that `PagesController does not exist.`

Can someone please help me, feel like i've tried 100 options, from previous threads.

I have rewrite enabled, i've modified httpd.conf and my .htaccess

Here is my controller,

```
<?php 
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;  
    use App\Http\Requests; 
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controllers;         
    use Illuminate\Http\Request; 

    class PageController extends Controller { 
            public function about() { 
                    $first = "Nichlas"; 
                    return view ('pages.about', compact('first')); 
            }
     }
```

Comment: are you using namespaces ? Please provide some code in detail !

Comment: This is my PagesController.php
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PageController extends Controller {
 public function about()
 {
  $first = "Nichlas";
  return view ('pages.about', compact('first'));
 }
}

Comment: I just found the error. I had class PageController instead of class PagesController. Sorry for the inconvience and thank you Irfan :-)

Comment: No Problem at all, I was customizing your question to easily understandable. Glad if you have resolved.

Comment: Yes, im not used to Stackoverflow. Ill remember next time i have a question :-)